# Set environment from docker-compose to angular container

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

Im trying to run my angular app on docker and past environment from docker run.

My dockerfile:

```
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:17.6-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./


RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:1.21.6-alpine

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/content-admin-frontend /etc/nginx/html

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/bin/sh",  "-c",  "exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]
```

My src/config.json file:

```
{
    "api":"http://localhost/api/v1/",
    "language":"en"
}
```

My start container command:

docker run -p  4200:80 -e api='test'  -d contentadminfrontend

I don't heave idea how to replace this values :(

Comment: try this - docker-compose --env-file ./config/.env.dev up

Answer (score 0):

Which angular version you are using?
I am using Angular7 in Docker with nginx.
Please find the below start command:

```html
docker run -p 4200:80 -e NODE_ENV=${ENV} -d contentadminfrontend
```

where ${ENV} will be your environment name.

Comment: you could use a hardcoded value too so you wont need to declare another env var.

Comment: Yes I am using Jenkins pipeline where I am replacing ENV variable. That's why I added it.